# why hair particles do not drop down

Tags: particles

I have created a mesh feather shape. I added the hair particles. When i press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to play animation they do not drop down. I have a default sphere and added same particles settings on it they do on the sphere.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help why they do not fall down on my mesh. Thanks

Comment: perhaps you didn't click on the Hair Dynamics option for the feather?

Comment: @moonboots It is on in both

Comment: I don't know enough about Hair Dynamics, but it looks like when the hairs are straight vertical they don't fall, maybe if you rotate a bit your feather or add a wind, it will work, anyway it's not a solution, but it would explain why